# How can I use the port of a server running on localhost in kubernetes running spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, localhost, portforwarding

I am new to Kubernetes and kubectl. I am basically running a GRPC server in my localhost. I would like to use this endpoint in a spring boot app running on kubernetes using kubectl on my mac. If I set the following config in application.yml and run in kubernetes, it doesn't work. The same config works if I run in IDE.

```
grpc:
  client:
    local-server:
      address: static://localhost:6565
      negotiationType: PLAINTEXT
```

I see some people suggesting port-forward, but it's the other way round (It works when I want to use a port that is already in kubernetes from localhost just like the tomcat server running in kubernetes from a browser on localhost)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: testspringconfigvol
  labels:
    app: testspring
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testspringconfigvol
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testspringconfigvol
    spec:
      initContainers:
      # taken from https://gist.github.com/tallclair/849601a16cebeee581ef2be50c351841
      # This container clones the desired git repo to the EmptyDir volume.
      - name: git-config
        image: alpine/git # Any image with git will do
        args:
          - clone
          - --single-branch
          - --
          - https://github.com/username/fakeconfig
          - /repo # Put it in the volume
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1 # Any non-root user will do. Match to the workload.
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /repo
          name: git-config
      containers:
      - name: testspringconfigvol-cont
        image: username/testspring
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:  
        - mountPath: /usr/local/lib/config/
          name: git-config
      volumes:
        - name: git-config
          emptyDir: {}
```

What I need in simple terms:

Ports having some server in my localhost:
`localhost`:6565, `localhost`:6566, I need to access these ports some how in my kubernetes. Then what should I set it in application.yml config? Will it be the same `localhost`:6565, `localhost`:6566 or `how-to-get-this-ip`:6565, `how-to-get-this-ip`:6566.

Comment: Sorry, which `localhost`?  The physical host itself, the Docker for Mac or Minikube VM, and the pod each separately route `localhost` to themselves, so saying something is running "on localhost" is pretty ambiguous.  (And correspondingly, calls out of the pod on `localhost` will get returned to the pod and not anywhere else.)

Comment: The grpc servers are on the physical host and available on ports 6565 and 6566. I am trying to access them from the pods in minikube.  I haven't changed the config which is the address value in the above config.

Comment: So basically I am trying to access service running on host os from inside minikube. @david-maze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the vmware host ip using minikube with this command `minikube ssh "route -n | grep ^0.0.0.0 | awk '{ print \$2 }'"`. For me it's `10.0.2.2` on Mac. If using Kubernetes on Docker for mac, it's `host.docker.internal`.

By using these commands, I managed to connect to the services running on host machine from kubernetes.

Comment: Note for windows (PowerShell) users. Quotes should be different and escaped (or you'll get  'awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token' error):
`minikube ssh 'route -n | grep ^0.0.0.0 | awk \"{ print \$2 }\"'`